# How to find sum of all the GCDs of all the subarrays of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

Given an array A of length n = 10^5. I have to find the sum of GCD of all subarrays of this array efficiently.

```
import math
def lgcd(a):
    g = a[0]
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        g = math.gcd(g,a[i])
    return g

n = int(input())
A = list(map(int,input().split()))
ans = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        ans+=lgcd(A[i:j+1])

print(ans)
```

Comment: Sorry for storing the GCDs, I need to calculate the sum of GCDs only.

Comment: What is the maximum value for an element in the array?

Comment: @user3386109 1<=A[i]<=10^8

Comment: @MohanSinghcan you give me the link of the problem you are trying to solve? Will like to solve it myself.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that should be marked is that GCD(A[i-1 : j]) * d = GCD(A[i : j]) where d is natural number. So for the fixed subarray end, there will be some blocks with equal GCD, and there will be no more than *log n* blocks, since GCD in one block is the divisor of GCD of another block, and, therefore, is at least two times smaller.

So the next algorithm can be used: for all elements in array lets assume that they are last elements of the subarray, and then will find all blocks of equal GCDs and add to our total sum *block size \* block gcd*.

To fastly find blocks with equal GCD you can use a segment tree. To find a block you just need to find the longest subarray ending in fixed element, where gcd is smaller, then on your previously checked block. To do it just binary search this index and check condition using queries in the segment tree.

This algorithm is O(n log<sup>2</sup> n log k) where k is a maximal number in the array.

**EDIT**

It makes more sense to use the sparse table instead of the segment tree. Everything else will stay the same. With this change time complexity will be O(n log n log k)

#### Example:

For A = [120 ,15 ,36, 20]

For 120 there is only one block - 120 (GCD(120) = 120). So Total sum is now 0 + 120 * 1 = 120

For 15 there is only one block of length two - 15 (GCD(15) = 15, GCD(120, 15) = 15). So the total sum is now 120 + 15 * 2 = 150.

For 36 there are two blocks - 36 (GCD(36) = 36) and 3 (GCD(15, 36) = GCD(120, 15, 36) = 3). So the total sum is now 192 = 150 + 36 * 1 + 3 * 2 = 192.

For 20 there are three blocks - 20 (GCD(20) = 20), 4 (GCD(36, 20) = 4) and 1 (GCD(15, 36, 20) = GCD(120, 15, 36, 20) = 1). So the total sum is now 102 + 20 * 1 + 4 * 1 + 1 * 2 = 218, and it is the answer

Comment: Can you please explain your algorithm by an example?
Suppose for A = [120 ,15 ,36, 20], ans = 218.

Comment: For 120 there is only one block - 120. So Total sum is now 0 + 120 * 1 = 120.
For 15 there is only one block of length two - 15. So the total sum is now 120 + 15 * 2 = 150.
For 36 there are two blocks - 36 (length 1) and 3 (length 2). So the total sum is now 192 = 150 + 36 * 1 + 3 * 2 = 192.
For 20 there are three blocks - 20 (length 1), 4 (length 1) and 1 (length 2). So the total sum is now 102 + 20 * 1 + 4 * 1 + 1 * 2 = 218.

Comment: @RomanSvistunov can I use this algorithm to get the count of all gcd(s) of all sub-arrays?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri that will work but still you will get time out for the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: `GCD(A[i-1 : j]) * d = GCD(A[i : j]) where d is natural number...`. GCD of the greater range should be <= GCD of smaller range where the smaller range is overlapped by the greater range. Also, that's still 0(n^2).

Comment: @AJ.S first [i-1 : j] is a greater range than [I : j], second - `find the longest subarray ending in fixed element` meant doing so by binary search. But thanks for pointing this out, my asymptotic bound was calculated without respect to this additional binary search, so I edited the post correcting this error. Also, it might be possible to find maximal subarray without using binary search, but I can't see how right now.

Answer (score 1):

> The efficient method is observing the problem statement closely. Example we have array as 
>   [1,2,3,45]. Now when we find GCD of [1,2] and we need to find GCD of [1,2,3] we can 
>   simply do it with GCD(GCD([1,2]),3). So here are overlapping subproblems. So just store the result.
>
> A subarray of length k is constructed from subarray of length k-1 + 1 element. So GCD of subarray including k'th element is GCD of k'th element and GCD of subarray of k-1 elements i.e. GCD(GCD(A[i:i+k],A[k]).

```
final = dict()

def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return gcd(b, a % b)


A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
dp = [[-1 for _ in range(len(A))] for _ in range(len(A))]

# Set GCD of single element as the elemnt itself
for i in range(len(A)):
    dp[i][i] = A[i]

# For every other subarrays of length l
# Calculate gcd using  length l - 1
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):

        dp[i][j] = gcd(dp[i][j - 1], A[j])
        final[tuple(A[i: j + 1])] = dp[i][j]

print(final)
```

Comment: It's still O(n^2). I need to do it better than this.

Comment: I think this will be the best case as we need the answer for each subarray.

Comment: I think we need a solution of complexity O(n logn). That's usually the case when n~10^5.

Comment: @Kamesh-Bakshi I want to extend it for multiple queries for all subarrays of a given range, that's why a O(log n) solution is needed for a single query.

Comment: In that case, you will need to look into segment tree. It will give the answer to all queries in O(log n). But you will need to store the GCD of all subarray.